# How can I export images path with require() from one index.js file in react naitve?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, image

I want to export all images from one file which index.js so that If in future I have to change the path of image then I have to only make changes in one file.

like this:

```
export {default as avatar} from './avatar.png';
export {default as career} from './PsychoScreenImages/career.jpeg';
export {default as application} from './redeemIcons/application.jpeg';
export {default as featured} from './redeemIcons/featured.jpeg';
```

But I can't do like this `require(avatar)` as it requires the only a path. So, How can I export and import images from just one js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file that itself exports the image paths require within it. As shown below -

Just you can name this file `imagepaths.js`

```js
export default {
  logo: require('./images/logo.png'),
  newLogo: require('./images/logo-new.png')
}
```

Now import this and use as-

```js
import imagePath from 'imagePath';

return (
    <>
        <Image source={imagePath.logo} />
        <Image source={imagePath.newLogo} />
    </>
)
```